# Is it safe to mark the FileManager Sendable?

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

I have an extension on the [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) that uses the new concurrency:
`try await Task.detached(priority: .background)` closure and then uses `self` to create a directory enumerator with `FileManager.enumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:)`.

On Xcode 14 I get the warning:
[image]

I am trying to figure out if it's safe to mark `FileManager` as `Sendable`:
`extension FileManager: @unchecked Sendable {}`.

It seems that `FileManager` is thread safe with some caveats: `The methods of the shared FileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely.`

Any reason why Apple did not mark the `FileManager` as `Sendable`? I would think they have a reason not to do that in which case I should definitely avoid marking it sendable, or maybe they just did not get to it?

Full code (adapted from [src](https://gist.github.com/NikolaiRuhe/408cefb953c4bea15506a3f80a3e5b96)):

```
func allocatedSizeOfDirectory(at directoryURL: URL) async throws -> UInt64 {
    try await Task.detached(priority: .background) {
        // The error handler simply stores the error and stops traversal
        var enumeratorError: Error?
        func errorHandler(_: URL, error: Error) -> Bool {
            guard (error as NSError).code != NSFileReadNoPermissionError else { return true }
            enumeratorError = error
            return false
        }

        // We have to enumerate all directory contents, including subdirectories.
        let enumerator = self.enumerator(at: directoryURL,
                                         includingPropertiesForKeys: Array(allocatedSizeResourceKeys),
                                         options: [],
                                         errorHandler: errorHandler)!

        // We'll sum up content size here:
        var accumulatedSize: UInt64 = 0

        // Perform the traversal.
        for item in enumerator {

            // Bail out on errors from the errorHandler.
            if enumeratorError != nil { break }

            // Add up individual file sizes.
            let contentItemURL = item as! URL
            accumulatedSize += try contentItemURL.regularFileAllocatedSize()
        }

        // Rethrow errors from errorHandler.
        if let error = enumeratorError { throw error }

        return accumulatedSize
    }.value
}
```

Comment: Wondering why would you need to send a `FileManager` across concurrency boundaries. Also, think about the `errorHandler` parameter - what if multiple threads call the `enumerator` method at the same time, on the same `FileManager` instance, what if the `errorHandler` callback is internally saved into a property?

Comment: Good questions @Cristik! I used the new concurrency for this method to gain some exposure to this new technology, but it might not be the perfect tool for the job. Xcode 13 did not have any warnings, but it seems Xcode 14 detected an issue that is currently a warning but will be an error in Swift 6.x
As to why I need to send the `FileManager` across conc. boundaries: I wouldn't need it, but it might just happen I guess after the suspension point coming back there is no guarantee that you continue on the same thread. In this case the concern is `self`.

Comment: Don’t know if it is safe, however conforming a standard library type to a standard library protocol is not recommended by Apple. If Apple adds this conformance later it will cause issues: what conformance (yours or Apple) will prevail?

Comment: This should be completely safe given that `FileManager` is thread-safe per the documentation.
The one risk here is the delegate (which shouldn't be set on the `default` instance anyways). If the delegate is set, I'm guessing delegate callbacks would happen based on the thread the functions are invoked on.